# Matplotlib + Latex Rendering / twinx(): wrong font on secondary y-axis?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using matplotlib to generate diagrams with text being latex-rendered. Now there's this tricky problem which I don't seem to be able to solve by myself..

The secondary y-axis generated using twinx() shows the wrong font for ticklabels and ylabel! What am I doing wrong? 
Here is what I do.

```
    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
    from matplotlib import rc
    from matplotlib.figure import Figure               
    from matplotlib.axes import Axes    
    from matplotlib.lines import Line2D

    rc('font',**{'family':'serif','sans-serif':['Computer Modern Roman']})
    rc('text', usetex=True)

    fig = plt.figure(figsize = (4,4) )                                
    ax = Axes(fig, [.1,.1,.8,.8])  
    ax_ = ax.twinx()                            
    fig.add_axes(ax)

    fig.add_axes(ax_)       

    l = Line2D([0, 1],[0, 1], color='r')

    ax.set_ylabel(r'Label')
    ax_.set_ylabel(r'Label')

    ax.add_line( l )

    plt.show()
```

Versions in use: 
matplotlib 0.99.1.1
tex.. no idea
; all on linux

ps:
rendering text, title and so on works fine this way, it is only the secondary y-axis that is behaving rather badly!

Comment: The font on the secondary axis is 'stronger', I don't know the correct typographical expression.

Comment: I could not reproduce your problem. I am using matplotlib 1.1. You can try saving the figure as pdf and check if it still exist.

Comment: @nina can you upload an image of what you are seeing?  I also can not reproduce the problem with 1.1.1rc

Comment: As mentioned below, I am going to try to tackle the problem by updating my matplotlib. Would have uploaded an image, but it's not possible yet for me, need more reputation first.. I'll report what happened as soon as got round to do it!

Answer (score 0):

The best answer to this may be to update your Matplotlib version if it is at all possible. If subsequently you are still getting issues at least it would mean that you could open a bug report on the [Matplotlib GitHub site](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/new).

Comment: Ok, I think I'll find time to do the update tomorrow, thanks so far, anyway! I hope that does the trick!

Answer (score 0):

I am maybe a little bit late, but no one as written a good answer yet. I have got the same problem and solved it by writing the ticklabels in latex:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
labels = [r"$1.$", r"$1.5$", r"$2.$"]
ticks = [1., 1.5, 2.]
plt.set_xticks(ticks)
plt.set_xticklabels(labels)
```